# How executing mysql query into cf7 push button action

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I use a form7 contact form with wordpress for a gites booking site. my problem is when the client presses on a button of the form I have to execute a mysql request which returns a price and I have to display it on the form how do I proceed knowing that the form exists as well as the treatment of the button as below can someone help me please

```
<label> Votre nom (obligatoire)
[text* your-name] </label>

<label> Votre adresse de messagerie (obligatoire)
[email* your-email] </label>

<label> Objet
[text your-subject] </label>

<label> Votre message
[textarea your-message] </label>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Calcul du séjour</button>

[submit "Envoyer"]

<script>
function myFunction() 
{
   alert('sent ok');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to add price to an input field or just want to show the price in the form?

Comment: Just show the price in the form. The table exit yet in Mysql wordpress server

Comment: Thank à lot Jainil I try this afternoon and I come back to you if I some question. See you later

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery` and `Ajax` request.

In the form add HTML to show price and change button as below:

```
<span class="price"></span>

<button type="button" class="calc_price">Calcul du séjour</button>
```

Create following function in the theme's `function.php` file:

```
// define the actions for the two hooks created, first for logged in users and the next for logged out users
add_action("wp_ajax_calculate_price", "calculate_price");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_calculate_price", "calculate_price");

function calculate_price() {
    // Get Price Code here

    echo $price;

    die();
}
```

Create a JS file and enqueue it like below:

```
function script_enqueue() {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-ajax-script.js', array('jquery') );
      wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_enqueue' );
```

In `JS` file add below `jQuery` code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
   jQuery(".calc_price").click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        jQuery.ajax({
            type : "get",
            url : my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'calculate_price'
            },
            success: function(response) {
                jQuery("span.price").html(response.data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200678/discussion-on-answer-by-jainil-how-executing-mysql-query-into-cf7-push-button-ac).